# Issue in Accessing Data from Sitecore using Glass Mapper

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper

I have items with children in content tree as below and has to be shown in the same page. We have created a Stronglytyped View of type `ModelA` for the page:

```
public class ModelA
{
        public IEnumerable<ModelA > item1 { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ModelB> item2{ get; set; }
}
```

Content Tree is:

```
Item1(Based on Template A and Created ModelA to access)
---Children11(Based on Template A and Created ModelA to access))
---Children12(Based on Template A and Created ModelA to access))

Item2(Based on Template A and Created ModelA to access))
---Children21(Based on Template B and Created ModelB to access))
---Children22(Based on Template B and Created ModelB to access))
```

We are using **GlassMapper** to get data and so we have defined `ModelA` for `Children11`, `Children12` and `ModelB` for `Children21`, `Children22`.

I am able to get children for `item1` but not for `item2` has it is `null`. Is it because glass mapper is not able to find them and map it of type `ModelB`?

Comment: Can you show the code for the mappings? Specifically which attributes are being used.

Comment: Please add the full model and any mappings you might have, the above class would be insufficient to carry out the mappings you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to use the SitecoreChildren attribute on the properties to make this work...